# Changing color of label when selected

Tags: javascript

Please see [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/DEn9s/1/) for what I am doing.
I am trying to make the labels change color if it is selected. If another option is selected, the previous one will change back to the original color.

I had googled and tried someone's code

```
function checkState(id){
    var layer = document.getElementById(id);
    if(layer.childNodes[0].checked === true){
    layer.style.backgroundColor = "#0099CC";
    }
else{
    layer.style.backgroundColor = "#eee" ;
};
}
```

but this causes the previously chosen option to not change back to the original color when the second option is chosen. 
No JQuery, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEn9s/3/) corrected to actually work. In future, make sure your Fiddle actually works before you post it.

Among other things, I have fixed the syntax errors (`for( int i...)`? Really?) and I have changed the "set the colour back to normal" to just clear the style, allowing the hover effect to continue working.

In future versions of CSS, you will be able to do something like this:

```
!label>input:checked {background-color:#09c;}
```

The `!` will determine the "target" of the selector. Note that syntax isn't definite yet.

Comment: So I was nearly right! I didn't know how to use fiddle, shouldnt have put in the script tags, I see. Thanks. (for(int i=0; i < j; i++) is from java, I have no prior knowledge of javascript.)